# Calculating the distribution of time until the first point occurs in a point process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I have a continuous time-dependent point process $\mathcal{X}({t})$ where $t\in[0,1]$ and I am trying to compute the distribution of the occurrence of the first point. The information I have is

$$P(\text{a point occuring at time t}| \text{no point before time t})=\frac{t^3}{3}$$

I am looking to compute

$$P(\text{the first point occurs before or at t})=1-P(\text{no point occurs up to and including time $t$})$$

This information should be all I need to calculate this distribution, but I am unsure how to compute it. Would I have to integrate over $P(\text{a point occuring at time t}| \text{no point before time t})$ from $0$ to $t$?

Comment: This doesn't seem well-defined. Certainly $t > 3^{1/3}$ makes the conditional probability false, right?

Comment: Sorry t is between 0 and 1 in this example

Comment: Really? where did the rest of the probability go? I would think $t \in [0,3^{1/3}]$.

Comment: Regardless - I don't see how without more information you can calculate. You don't have information on the joint distribution. I don't see how it can be integrated away.